# Flutter Document Picker

Tags: flutter

I try to use `flutter_document_picker` package this way:

```
FlutterDocumentPickerParams params = FlutterDocumentPickerParams(
    allowedFileExtensions: ['csv'],
    allowedUtiTypes: ['com.mydomain.csv'],
    allowedMimeTypes: ['application/*'],
    invalidFileNameSymbols: ['/'],
);
```

The problem is that in the list of files the .csv file is greyed out and not selectable i.e. not pickable (at least on Android). What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your allowedMimeTypes to `'*/*'` or `'text/plain'`